# Substituting code in place of variable (for that code) not working - Bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, html, templates, bigcommerce

I need to alter two templates, product.html and ProductDetails.html so I can revise the layout for specific products etc.  I can not figure out how these two files are connected because they don't seem to interact as I would expect - let me tell you what I mean:

1 - If I copy all the content from ProductDetails.html and put it into product.html in place of the %%Panel.ProductDetails%% template variable, it seems to me that it should work, but instead completely breaks, throws errors.

2 - I create a clone from product.html named productX.html (custom layout).
    I create a clone of ProductDetails.html named ProductDetailsX.html.
    Changing the template variable %%Panel.ProductDetails%% in EITHER product.html or productX.html to %%Panel.ProductDetailsX%% also breaks and throws errors.

I have created custom layouts before and replaced template variables with its actual code on many occasions, so I can not find a reason for any of this behavior.  I need to alter product.html which I can do by creating a custom template (productX.html), but if I can't alter the styling or code of the different pieces of the template variables within it...it doesn't make sense that this would be the case.

A - Why won't a template variable (Panel) that is a reference to a clone of ProductDetails.html work?

B - Why doesn't %%Panel.ProductDetailsX%% work, but %%Panel.ProductDetails%% does?

C - How do I get past this and what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the variables available in the ProductDetails panel are only available in that panel. Copying the content out or trying to clone it to make it custom will likely cause the behavior you have seen for these reasons.

There is some documentation available about what variables or panels can be called per layout, panel, and snippet. For the product details panel, you can see that [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/blueprint/panels/#productdetails-panel).

If you can explain further the changes you are trying to make, we can look at providing a more holistic answer to the question posed.